# Printing the frequency of sequences in a fasta file (python)

Tags: python, sorting, sequence, biopython, fasta

I am attempting to find the diversity of the population of sequences from a large fasta file. The ultimate goal is to create a histogram of the distribution.

I've written the code below to count the number of times each sequence occurs in the fasta file. I've done this to add the count to the end of the id. Instead of this formating, I would like to print an output file that simply says one sequence occurs x times. y sequences occur z times, and so on, without the sequence and id.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict

dedup_records = defaultdict(list)
for record in SeqIO.parse("filename.fasta", "fasta"):
    # Use the sequence as the key and then have a list of id's as the value
    dedup_records[str(record.seq)].append(record.id)
with open("filename_output.fasta", 'w') as output:
    for seq, ids in sorted(dedup_records.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[1]), reverse=True):
        output.write(">{}_counts{}\n".format(ids[0], len(ids)))
        output.write(seq + "\n")
```

[The image shows a snippet of the output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnP5G.png)

From this image I would like the output to print:
1 sequence occurs 1885 times
1 sequence occurs 1099 times
1 sequence occurs 280 times.

Additionally, when multiple sequences occur the same amount of times, they are each printed out separately. I'm not sure how to combine those.[EX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lFTz.png)

Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Thank you so much.

Comment: So, is anything going wrong?

Comment: I'm hoping to print out solely                                                        w sequence(s) occurs x times                                             y sequence(s) occurs z times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### collections.Counter()

Use a Counter, twice.  Something like this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import Counter

# counts the number of times each sequence occurs
sequences = SeqIO.parse("filename.fasta", "fasta")
seq_counts = Counter(str(record.seq) for record in sequences)

# counts how many repeat 2, 3, 4, ... times
count_repeats = Counter(seq_counts.values())

with open("filename_output.fasta", 'w') as output:
    for repeat, num_seqs in count_repeats.most_common():
        output.write(f">{num_seqs} sequences occur {repeat} times\n")
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. This did exactly was I was looking for.